# What sql server isolation level should I choose to prevent concurrent reads?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have the following transaction:

1. SQL inserts a 1 new record into a table called tbl_document
2. SQL deletes all records matching a criteria in another table called tbl_attachment
3. SQL inserts multiple records into the tbl_attachment

Until this transaction finishes, I don't want others users to be aware of the (1) new records in tbl_document, (2) deleted records in tbl_attachment, and (3) modified records in tbl_attachment.

Would Read Committed Isolation be the correct isolation level?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  If it's 2005 or later, this should be handled correctly automatically (by default) by snapshotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

   insert into tbl_document ...
   delete tbl_attachment where ...
   inserts into tbl_attachment ...

COMMIT
```

you may block/lock users until you are finished and commit/rollback the transaction. Also, someone could SELECT your rows from tbl_attachment after your insert into tbl_document but before your delete.  If you need to prevent that do this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

   select tbl_attachment with (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) where ...
   insert into tbl_document ...
   delete tbl_attachment where ...
   inserts into tbl_attachment ...

COMMIT
```

or just delete tbl_attachment before the insert into tbl_document and forget the select with the locking hints.

Comment: I notice that you are not specifying the isolation level. Is this because SQL Server 2005 defaults to read commited? Also would this code work the same if I did an update instead of an insert on tbl_document?

Comment: if everyone running your application is using `read commited` then they can only read changes that were commited.  if you try to read data that is changing (transaction is still in progress) you wait until the transaction is complete before your read is processed.  Like the delete in your question, there is a timing issue. Someone will be able to read the rows you *intend* to update in the time between your `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and your actual `UPDATE` of them.  With insert, this is not an issue (they are new, they don't exist until you put them in).

Comment: continued..  Locks are acquired as you proceed through the transaction.  If you do a lot in the transaction before your `update` and you want to *freeze* people from reading those rows from the moment the transaction starts, then you might try using the `SELECT ... WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)` at the start of the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter the transaction isolation level of your **writes**. What is important is the isolation level of your **reads**. Normally reads will **not** see your insert/update/delete until is committed. The only isolation level can does see uncommitted changes is READ UNCOMMITTED. If the concurrent thread uses dirty reads, there is *nothing* you can do in the write to prevent it.

READ UNCOMMITTED can be either set as an isolation level, or requested explicitly with a (NOLOCK) table hint. Dirty reads can see inconsistent transaction data (eg. the debit does not balance the credit of an operation) and also can cause duplicate reads (read the same row multiple times from a table) and trigger mysterious key violations.

Comment: won't snapshot isolation will prevent READ UNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK reads?

Comment: @KM: no. You can test that urself easily. An uncommitted write from a SNAPSHOT transaction is perfectly visible to a concurrent UNCOMMITTED read.